# Is the Wall of Blades maneuver affected by AC penalties?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, armor-class, combat-maneuver

Do AC penalties (and bonuses, for that matter) apply to the Wall of Blades manuever?

Bob the martial adept has prepared Wall of Blades this morning.

He also acquired Shocktrooper last week.

Bob's AC is 20. He charges, taking a -10 penalty on AC because of Shocktrooper. Then a giant tries to swat him, so he uses Wall of Blades, with his roll ending up a 25.

So the question is, does the giant roll his original attack against an AC of 25 (the roll) or 15 (the roll minus the penalty)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Book of Nine Swords:

> [...] Use the higher of you AC or your attack roll as your effective AC against the incoming attack. [...]

The use of the word "effective"* makes me thinks that AC's penalty don't apply to the attack roll, meaning that in your example, Bob would have an (effective) AC of 25.

---

- : After a [search for the word "effective" on the SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/search.htm?q=effective), I came to the conclusion that "effective" means "after calculation" in that context.